# iosslider in famo.us surface doesn't work when the app installed on mobile using phonegap

Tags: jquery, angularjs, slider, famo.us

I created iosslider using jquery and i put it in famo.us surface in famo.us/angular..it works fine on browser but when i install the app on mobile using phonegap it doesn't work, it works fine on mobile if it's out of the famo.us surface, my code

```
  $('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
      desktopClickDrag: true,
      snapToChildren: true,
    });
```

i think famo.us doesn't know desktopClickDrag, i don't know if its a famo.us bug, any help would be appreciated thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Famo.us framework intercepts all the touch events on mobile, since it needs to control them for things like it's ScrollView. That's why your slider works fine on mobile but not inside a Surface. Check out their own [slider](https://github.com/Famous/widgets/blob/master/Slider.js), which works with GenericSync events.